# Install gcc 4.7 but cannot run program sucessfully

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

I need to use C++ 11, so I updated my GCC from 4.1 to 4.7. I compile the source code and make install it. `gcc -version` will show 4.7.0 (everything looks good). I compiled my program using:

```
g++ -O2 -std=c++11 -o wdSer wdSer.cpp
```

After that I run my program `./wdSer`, there are some information as follows:

```
./wdSer: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by ./wdSer)
./wdSer: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.5' not found (required by ./wdSer)
./wdSer: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.10' not found (required by ./wdSer)
./wdSer: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by ./wdSer)
```

Who can tell me how to solve it?

Comment: Where did you install it?  Did you overwrite the system-provided versions of the libraries, or did you install it in `/usr/local` or some other location? If you overwrote the system versions, you're a braver man than I am. If you installed it in some other location, you probably have to ensure that the new libraries are picked up in preference to the system ones, possibly with `-R` options or its equivalent at link time, possibly with `ld.so.conf` or its equivalent (which platform are you on, in fact), possibly with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or its equivalent. I'm curious, why 4.7.0 instead of 4.8.2?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I install in /home/gcc4.7 , I didn't overwrite the system-provided. So you means I need to add some class path ?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler There are some error when I compile the 4.8.2 source code, but 4.7 is OK.

Comment: I'm relieved to hear you used `/home/gcc4.7` for the installation; it's roughly equivalent to what I do (I tend to use `/usr/gcc/v4.8.2` etc, but it is the same process).  It isn't 'classpath' precisely, but it is roughly equivalent to that.  Basically, your program needs to be told to look for `libstdc++.so.6` under `/home/gcc4.7/`, in the `lib` or perhaps `lib64` directory.  My Ubuntu VM has GCC 4.8.1 installed by the system, and where I have it installed on my Mac may not help much, but the 64-bit library is in the `lib` directory and the 32-bit version in `lib/i386`.

Comment: So, you need to find where the GCC 4.7.0 library is installed.  When you link the program, you could add an option `-R/home/gcc4.7/lib` (with the correct pathname) and that should mean that the library will be found in the correct place.  You might be OK setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include `/home/gcc4.7/lib`, but programs run by root won't pay attention to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. You could adjust the `ld.so.conf` file to specify the new directory, but this would affect all programs on the system — be cautious. You can use `ldd ./wdSer` to see which libraries it loads.

Comment: You could also consider a wrapper script for each program that you compile with the new library which sets LD_LIBRARY_PATH appropriately.  That tends to be a short-term fix.  The long-term solution is probably to upgrade the o/s to a version that uses GCC 4.7.x or later as the default compiler version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First try this:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./wdSer
```

/usr/local/lib64 is the default library directory for a 64bit build of gcc .
Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to contain that directory tells the linker to look in that directory for library files.

If that does not work, look at the output of g++ -v

On my system, I get this:

```
$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/gcc-4.8.2/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../gcc-4.8.2/configure --prefix=/usr/local/gcc-4.8.2 --with-isl=/usr/local/isl-0.12.2 --with-cloog=/usr/local/cloog-0.18.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.2 (GCC)
```

In this output, you are looking for a directory following --prefix. Add /lib64 to the end of that prefix, and you'll have your library directory.
On my system, it's /usr/local/gcc-4.8.2 , so I need the linker to look in /usr/local/gcc-4.8.2/lib64 to find my libstdc++ .
So I run programs like this:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/gcc-4.8.2/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./a.out
```

If you don't want to set your LD_LIBRARY_PATH before running your programs, you should build them with -Wl,-rpath= , like this:

```
$ g++  -std=c++11 -o wdSer -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib64/ wdSer.cc
```

You can use ldd on a program to see where the shared libraries it is linked to are found:

```
$ ldd a.out
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff8a506000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/local/gcc-4.8.2/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fa3c6aaf000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa3c6811000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/local/gcc-4.8.2/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fa3c67fa000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa3c646f000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa3c6bbc000)
```

Here, a.out is a program I built with the option -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/gcc-4.8.2/lib64 , so the linker looks there first, and finds the libstdc++ that goes with my gcc 4.8.2 install.

Please see the documention for the -v flag: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options (and search for -v )

the -Wl flag : http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options (and scroll down to the bottom)

and the -rpath flag: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.24/ld/Options.html#Options (and search for -rpath)